# Parsing JSON data and storing into a listview

Tags: android, json, string, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm currently developing a small android weather app. That passes through 3 strings to display three weather elements from the open source weatherAPI. I'm trying to display this in a `listview`. I got it working when passing in 1 string. But I'm having trouble passing in multiple strings. Any advice would be appreciated

```
ArrayList<Weather> weatherData = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    private ListView listView1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        String[] city = {
                new String("dublin,ire"),
                new String("London,uk")

        };
        for (int i = 0; i < city.length; ++i) {
            listView1.add(city[i]);
        }

        //String city2 = "Dublin,ire";
        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                                           Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                                           Log.d("MR.bool", "Button1 was clicked ");

                                           startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class));
                                       }
                                   });


                cityText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cityText);
                condDescr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.condDescr);
                temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);
                hum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hum);
                press = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.press);
                windSpeed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windSpeed);
                windDeg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windDeg);
                imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.condIcon);
                imgView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


                JSONWeatherTask task = new JSONWeatherTask();
                task.execute(new String[]{city});

                if (city.contains("uk")) {
                    imgView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.uk);
                } else if (city.contains("ire")) {
                    imgView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ireland);
                } else if (city.contains("de")) {
                    imgView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.germany);
                }
            }





            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }


            private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

                @Override
                protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
                    Weather weather = new Weather();
                    String data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

                    try {
                        weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

                        // Let's retrieve the icon
                        weather.iconData = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return weather;

                }






                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Weather weather) {
                    super.onPostExecute(weather);

                    if (weather.iconData != null && weather.iconData.length > 0) {
                        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(weather.iconData, 0, weather.iconData.length);
                        imgView.setImageBitmap(img);
                    }

                    else if(weatherData.size() > 0)
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter<Weather> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Weather>(MainActivity.this,
                                android.R.layout.activity_list_item, weatherData);

                        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

                        // here you can also define your custom adapter and set it to listView
                        //according to your own defined layout as items
                    }

                    cityText.setText(weather.location.getCity() + "," + weather.location.getCountry());
                    condDescr.setText(weather.currentCondition.getCondition() + "(" + weather.currentCondition.getDescr() + ")");
                    temp.setText("" + Math.round((weather.temperature.getTemp() - 273.15)) + "�C");
                    hum.setText("" + weather.currentCondition.getHumidity() + "%");
                    press.setText("" + weather.currentCondition.getPressure() + " hPa");
                    windSpeed.setText("" + weather.wind.getSpeed() + " mps");
                    windDeg.setText("" + weather.wind.getDeg() + "�");

                }


            }
        }
```

Comment: Please describe the "trouble" in detail.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Im trying to pass the 3 strings (The locations, for example "London,uk" , Paris,fr & Berlin, dn) to get the the parsed objects that display weather data all at once in a listview. I can only currently pass 1 string and it displays 1 individual weather object. So the overall trouble is instead of just passing in 1 string, I just want to accomplish parsing 3 weather objects at once with a array. Im new enough to android and i hope i explained that in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: Let us see you adapter. And you should add your cities in your ArrayList, not in  view.

Comment: Check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-json-parser/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson to parse the json.
I'm assuming that you are receiving a jsonArray. So, you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Weather> weatherArrayList = new ArrayList<Weather>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonArray jArray = jsonParser.parse(responseStr).getAsJsonArray();

for (JsonElement obj : jArray) {
   Weather weatherModel = gson.fromJson(response, Weather.class);
   weatherArrayList.add(weatherModel);
}
```

The code above parse the data in your json and adds them into your "weatherArrayList" this ArrayList you should place it in your adapter and just set in your listview.

This might be your custom adapter

```
public class WeatherAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Weather> {

    public WeatherAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
       // here you should set up the custom view. That is the view of each Item of your ListView

    }
}
```

I hope I helped you :)